# Informatica Incremental Load using greenplum writer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have a general question regarding the informatica incremental load process. Currently I am using the flow as source(extract)-->stage(load - find out inserts and updates)-->load into main table(inserts and updates).
For updates currently I am using update strategy and ODBC relational writer(update as update, delete) and its working fine. But drawback with approach is it is causing the data rows to update one by one as its not bulk update. DBA suggested to use greenplum writer(bulk update) instead of ODBC relational writer as this will enhance performance and update the data in bulk.

I have changed to greenplum writer and inserts are working fine but for updates ,I am not sure how to  to use greenplum writer as I have used update strategy in mapping so wanted to check what are the options to perform update as update and delete in greenplum writer similar to relational?

I have tried using greenplum writer with data driven property and provided the keys in match field(primary keys provided at informatica level) and update columns(all the columns except the primary key columns).Unfortunately whenever I am running the flow its throwing an error connection reset by peer. I have tried with relational writer and its working fine. Can you please help what to do in this case and if you have any sample for this.

Comment: Just a quick thought, as using Data Driven with Update Strategy is the least efficient way, can you try a separate session set to treat all source rows as updates and making sure it processes only this kind of rows? Bulk should then be used, AFAIR.

Comment: Thanks @Maciejg - I have tried it but looks like relational writer with odbc doesn't support bulk updates.Is there any other way?

Comment: ah, yes - ODBS does not support bulk. The only way is to use dedicated connector, here's the desription mentioning the bulk loads: https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration-connectors/current-version/greenplum-connector/introduction-to-greenplum-connector.html